# Print single unique row from dictionary without duplication

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm trying to figure out how to print a few unique values from a dictionary where multiple keys have the same values. The dictionary is created from a Pandas dataframe which in turn receives its data from mysql based on a user query, so the values being passed through will be highly variable.

So in my code, I've defined the dictionary as follows:

```
dict = {}
dict = df.to_dict()
```

For the sake of this exercise, let's say our dictionary looks like this:

```
{'id': {0: 'alpha', 1: 'alpha', 2: 'alpha', 3: 'beta', 4: 'beta', 5: 'beta'}, 
'born': {0: 1970, 1: 1970, 2: 1970, 3: 1985, 4: 1985, 5: 1985},
'first': {0: 'John', 1: 'John', 2: 'John', 3: 'John', 4: 'John', 5: 'John'},
'last': {0: 'Smith', 1: 'Smith', 2: 'Smith', 3: 'Smith', 4: 'Smith', 5: 'Smith'}}
```

What I'm trying to accomplish as output is to print a single set of values for ID "alpha" and ID "beta" in other words you'd have a final output something like this:

```
John Smith, born 1970
John Smith, born 1985
```

*** Note: As a little more background, I tried to accomplish this straight out of the pandas dataframe using `df.iterrows`, which worked fine except I couldn't figure out how to only show one row per unique ID. After reading around on some forums I got the impression that the only way to do so would be by creating a dictionary and using `set()` but that didn't seem to work either. When using `df.iterrows` this is what I got:

Input

```
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    print(row["first"], row["last"], row["born"])
```

Expectedly gave me

```
John Smith 1970
John Smith 1970
John Smith 1970
John Smith 1985
John Smith 1985
John Smith 1985
```

But I couldn't figure out how to get only the unique values (i.e. one John Smith born in 1970 and one John Smith born in 1985), which is how I wound up going the dictionary route. If anyone has a solve that doesn't involve the dictionary, it's certainly preferred, but at this point I'm looking for a solution using the dictionary.

Comment: I also wondered if groupby() is the way to go, but admittedly I'm not sure I know how I'd go about it in this case.

Comment: So much text... You know you can just call `.unique()` on a column?

Comment: I tried .unique() a while ago and got an error stating that it wasn't a valid argument or something to that effect. Does datatype matter?

Comment: This seems like a `.drop_duplicates` problem. Hard to know *exactly* what the subset needs to be from your example, but it could be as simple as `df.drop_duplicates('id')` or `df.drop_duplicates()`

Comment: I got excited when you suggested .drop_duplicates as I was sure it would work, but I couldn't get it to pare down the output at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This sounds like a simple:

```
for x in df.groupby(['first', 'last', 'born']).groups.keys():
    print '{} {}, born: {}'.format(*x)
```